# Rails 4 modal form_tag signup form on homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the error "param not found: user" when trying to submit my signup form from my homepage via a modal window.

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#create
param not found: user

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Here's the parameters that were passed in.

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"eXXn7+Rsf4SLciRPn4RW8Lw+3u6/FJZi8IW2XxekYsU=",
 "email"=>"asdf@asdf.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

Here's the users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def new
  user = User.new
end

def create
  user = User.new(user_params)
  if user.save
    auto_login(user)
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end

    private

        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
        end
end
```

Everything looks fine to me, but obviously something is wrong.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to nest your params to look like this:

```
{
  "user" =>
    {
      "email" => ...
    }
}
```

To do that is easier with `form_for`, but you can do the same with `form_tag` naming your inputs:

```
<input name="user[email]">
<input name="user[password]">
```

In erb you can use:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'user[email]' %>
```